# javascript file structures - any nice solutions?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

When I write PHP I might do something like put each object in it's own file, or, if I was better mannered I might even have folders for Models, Views and Controllers.

If you are writing lots of Javascript, what's the best way to avoid having one massive file?

I presume the spine / backbone frameworks would force me to do it their way, but is there another approach.

Is it best to combine the files server side or client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine files server-side is probably the best way.

When it comes to file organization you might want to take a look at solutions like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) which allow you to follow the [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) or [AMD](http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2011/04/27/using-amd-loaders-to-write-and-manage-modular-javascript/) patterns or a ruby solution like [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets)